# how can I write html code between PHP tag

Tags: php, html

I want to write html code between php without using of echo

I want to write like this

```
<?php 
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 ?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you're just writing HTML, then just write HTML.  There's no need to involve PHP.

Comment: "I want to" does not really explain the why.

Comment: If you don't want to use echo, you print :)

Comment: Next up: Writing javascript in php tags instead of javascript tags.

Comment: "and why everyone is down vote in my question" People are advising you of all sorts things and you seem to be ignoring them and concentrating on the answers. You won't get a good answer if you do not first concentrate on making sure your question is good, that includes interacting with the comments on your question, not ignoring them! You have wrapped code inside PHP tags (so PHP is required to deal with the code) but asked to output it without using echo. Other than print, there is no way to do this. If you provided a reason why (as asked several times) then we could perhaps guide you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use heredoc syntax.
https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
<?php 
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this:

```
<?php 
// PHP code
?>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
      <li>My Text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php
// PHP code
?>
```

Comment: i want to write it between php tag

Comment: i don't want write it after closing of php tag

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi **why**? We can't help without knowing what/how/why you want. This answer is perfectly fine as you have not given any details